# Including .rb file on view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i am including my own .rb(HintsHelper.rb) file on view. But it gives the following error. Why?
*uninitialized constant ActionView::Base::CompiledTemplates::HintsHelper*

then...

i included HintsHelper.rb in Application Helper file. but still it is giving me the following error.
*uninitialized constant ApplicationHelper::HintsHelper*

How to solve this problem. i want to access its(HintsHelper.rb) definitions on view. Plz help here...

thnx...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is solved...

i created a helper file name HintsHelper.rb from the terminal as... ruby script/generate helper Hints then i included this helper file in application helper file... from where you can use it from any view available... :)

Answer (score 0):

Use like

```
<%= helper HintsHelper%>
```

I think it should work